# Nodejs - Global or local initialisation of libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a bit confused as to which of the below is the better practice and why? In the first, we initialise the library globally and in the second case, its done inside a function.

Code 1

```
var twilio_client = require('twilio')(
  process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
  process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
);

function_sendSMS(from, to){
   twilio_client.messages.create({
     from: from,
     to: to,
     body: "You just sent an SMS from Node.js using Twilio!"
     }, function(err, message) {
     if(err) {
      console.error(err.message);
     }
  });
}
```

Code 2

```
function_sendSMS(from, to){

   var twilio_client = require('twilio')(
     process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
     process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN
   );

   twilio_client.messages.create({
     from: from,
     to: to,
     body: "You just sent an SMS from Node.js using Twilio!"
     }, function(err, message) {
     if(err) {
      console.error(err.message);
     }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stylistically this is really a matter of opinion.

However from a performance point of view, the first code example will be more efficient because it's cheaper to reference a variable in a parent scope than it is to go through any of node's module machinery, even when the module is cached after the first `require()`. I should also point out that in node v8.x, `require()` performance when loading a cached module has improved significantly (also `require()` for non-cached modules has improved *slightly* as well). You can see the difference in [this graph](https://benchmarking.nodejs.org/charts/require_cached.png) as of this writing.

Comment: Is the first case, the module will always be loaded, so wont it consume more memory/resources ?

Comment: It's not using any extra memory since it's a *reference* to the same object that is already in node's module cache.